# How to assert a generic list of integers with Hamcrest?

Tags: java, testing, junit, matching, hamcrest

I am trying to match a list of integers with Hamcrest, had look at a few examples online however I am getting runtime exceptions.

Can some please let me know what is the right syntax ?

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
assertThat((List<Object>) numbers, hasItem(hasProperty("value", is(1))));
assertThat((List<Object>) numbers, hasItem(hasProperty("value", is(2))));
assertThat((List<Object>) numbers, hasItem(hasProperty("value", is(3))));
assertThat((List<Object>) numbers, hasItem(hasProperty("value", is(4))));
assertThat((List<Object>) numbers, hasItem(hasProperty("value", is(5))));
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to assert exactly?

Comment: I don't know Hamcrest, but this looks like you want java.lang.Integer to have a property "value" (which it does not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the order of the list items doesn't matter:

```
assertThat(numbers, hasItems(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

If it does:

```
assertThat(numbers, is(equalTo(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))));
```

If the collection shouldn't include other elements then also check the size:

```
assertThat(numbers, hasSize(5));
```

Comment: If you want to test that `numbers` consists only of a certain set of items, be sure to assert the list's size in addition to doing the `hasItems` assertion described here.

Comment: @pholser That's good advice, I included it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There are other matchers that combine checking size and elements- see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To verify that the collection contains a specific item:

```
assertThat(numbers, hasItem(3));
```

To verify that the collection contains several items:

```
assertThat(numbers, hasItems(3, 4));
```

To verify that the collection contains exactly specific items:

```
assertThat(numbers, contains(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

To verify that the collection contains specific items, not worrying about order:

```
assertThat(numbers, containsInAnyOrder(5, 4, 3, 1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
assertThat(numbers, hasItem(1));
...
```

Or

```
assertThat(numbers, hasItems(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Order doesn't matter here.

Comment: @user465374: import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;